# incompatible character encodings ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 when loading Rails 3 SQLite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, encoding, character-encoding

I've built a Rails 3 application on my dev machine, and am ready to deploy.  I've setup the app on the production machine, and everything is running smoothly.  I've used `yaml_db` to dump the data from the database on the development machine, and am trying to load that into the database on the production box with `rake db:data:load RAILS_ENV=production`.  This is the output I get (with `--trace` enabled):

```
** Invoke db:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:schema:load
-- create_table("albums", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.1097s
-- create_table("composers", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0111s
-- create_table("tracks", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0123s
-- create_table("user_sessions", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0079s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.1218s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0160s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20110331123206, "db/migrate")
   -> 0.1078s
** Invoke db:data:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:data:load
rake aborted!
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:86:in `join'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:86:in `block in load_records'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:85:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:85:in `load_records'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:74:in `load_table'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in load_documents'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:60:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:60:in `block in load_documents'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:235:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:235:in `load_documents'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:235:in `load_documents'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:59:in `load_documents'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:57:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:56:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:31:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yaml_db-0.2.0/lib/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I've found about a million and one hits from other people with the same error (`incompatible character encodings ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8`), but most of them are trying to render UTF-8 encoded strings in views, etc.  Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

**EDIT:** Here's the line/block in question from `serialization_helper.rb`:

```
records.each do |record|
    quoted_values = record.zip(columns).map{|c| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(c.first, c.last)}.join(',')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO #{quoted_table_name} (#{quoted_column_names}) VALUES (#{quoted_values})")
end
```

Maybe there's a quick way to hack that up with `force_encoding()` or otherwise?  I'd try, but my Ruby fu just ain't that strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never sorted this out and I'd really rather not accept this workaround as the answer, but when no one else has anything to offer, c'est la vie.  As a workaround, and because I was loading the *entire* database, I just moved `production.sqlite` from the development box to the production box.  This doesn't feel quite right to me, but maybe I'm just paranoid.  Either way, it worked and everything's running smoothly now.